# Cannot Transfer Money to my Sandbox Business Account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, payment

I am integrating Paypal into an ASP.NET MVC 5 application, and I followed the steps in this post: [PayPal Integration](https://code.tutsplus.com/series/paypal-integration--cms-965).

I signed up on [Paypal developer](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/)(Paypal New Zealand, and thus the default currency is NZD) with my email:
my-name@hotmail.com. And two sandbox accounts were generated:

- buniness: my-name-facilitator@hotmail.com
- personal: my-name-buyer@hotmail.com (with balance 9999.00)

Created a REST App in dashboard:

[image]

Copied the client id and client secret to appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=_CHANGE_ME;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    },
    "Logging": {
      "IncludeScopes": false,
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Verbose",
        "System": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Information"
      }
    },
    "PayPal": {
      "clientId": "AZbTe-V1UhGgPkdALRNyIWAN5IZB9kfhYneI1iL-P5dnsE3IHbDyAjj5MeNFH_cNKl7eK2GVqCf5AJ_K",
      "clientSecret": "EFK1VysVtlj69_Wg9Zj7FTQi5jEb0nUF-cFORJ2cpIwP6j9fLaQTBsQy9V_Mo3DP9QcWT3zdZ6H3jZB4"
    }
  }
}
```

I updated the clientid and secret in PayPalConfiguration.cs as well:

```
    public static Dictionary<string, string> GetConfig()
    {
        // ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties(); // it doesn't work on ASPNET 5
    return new Dictionary<string, string>() {
        { "clientId", "AZbTe-V1UhGgPkdALRNyIWAN5IZB9kfhYneI1iL-P5dnsE3IHbDyAjj5MeNFH_cNKl7eK2GVqCf5AJ_K" },
        { "clientSecret", "EFK1VysVtlj69_Wg9Zj7FTQi5jEb0nUF-cFORJ2cpIwP6j9fLaQTBsQy9V_Mo3DP9QcWT3zdZ6H3jZB4" }
    };
}
```

Anyway, I used checkpoint to make sure that the program uses my new clientid and clientsecret when calling Paypal API.

When testing the Paypal program, I used the personal sandbox account to pay 100 dollars, and I can view that transaction record on https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/myaccount/

[image]

However, I cannot see any transaction record for the business account. What did I miss? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's showing in the buyer account you 'should' see it in the business sandbox which is odd, but wouldn't surprise me if PayPal is doing updates on their servers. What you 'may' want to do is hit up paypal tech support via their portal and paypal.com/mts, click contact support at the bottom and inquire. Could be a thing that it's just delayed for a bit, but will eventually show up. The alternative which I'm sure you already know is pull the response from the request and update any records or database's should you need. Hope this helps.

Comment: @GeekNinja thank you. I observed a delay, but the transaction was carried out one week ago, and the amount was deducted from the buyer's balance, while nothing happened to the recipient account, which is my business account.

Comment: sure, not acceptable. The best route would be to contact the tech team so they can dig into the issue.

Comment: On the screenshot you provided I see that -$100 is under faciliator account. Make sure that you try pay from buyer account.

Comment: My understanding is, that means the store name this payment is performed for.